# Apache spark java conditional replacement of column

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to replace a column in Dataset with value `Y` if it contains `X`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dataset<Row> DS;//already created dataset
    DS = DS.withColumn(column,when(col(column) === "X", "Y"));
}
```

It is giving me compilation error of `The method col(String) undefined` in Eclipse. I dont know what I am doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`functions` is a Scala object, so if you import `*` it has to be `static`:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
```

Comment: Like stated at the beginning - `function` is a Scala object, which translates to Java singleton. Simplifying, you import static methods from the object.